# Sencha Touch UI Button Icon: how to enable the use of the original color?

Tags: button, icons, sencha-touch, background-color

i created several buttons in a toolbar with custom icons. however, it turns out that these icons are all in black instead of their original colors. how could I make it by using CSS?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just apply a background colour to them using css, if you are properly applying the icons (with a mask), that should change its colour

Answer (score 1):

Also: you can inspect and remove rules for the -webkit-mask, and replace them with background images.